# How to check if file in ubuntu one cloud have been changed

Tags: ubuntu-one, python, ubuntu-one-api

I'm writing ubuntu one app in Python that Download files. It is working fine, but i want to modify it as if uploaded file changes, it downloads that file in current directory and so on. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? which api should i use.

Comment: The official Ubuntu One client already does this, and it is free software. Have you tried giving a quick look at its source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with using the REST API to talk to the Ubuntu One file sync service, as it has no method of pushing out notifications to your client program. The only way to do this is to use the persistent connection of the internal synchronization protocol, which the official `ubuntuone-client` code already uses.